# ruby on rails gives a No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the example in the book "Agile web development with rails" and am stuck. Hoping to get some help here. I created the depot app and then scaffolded the product resource:

rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal

All is good. I can hit "http://localhost:3000/products" and see the products with nice css as supplied by the book.

I did not touch the app for a couple of hours and decided to work through the example again. I can no longer hit the products page. I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/products"
```

I have not changed anything. The book suggested the I commit everything to git occassionally. I have retrieved back the last commit and still the same error. Other are also getting the same error and have the same question on stackoverflow, but I do not understand the answers.

Here are the files:

```
routes.rb
Depot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
```

routes command:

```
rake routes
    products GET    /products(.:format)          products#index
             POST   /products(.:format)          products#create
 new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)      products#new
edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format) products#edit
     product GET    /products/:id(.:format)      products#show
             PUT    /products/:id(.:format)      products#update
             DELETE /products/:id(.:format)      products#destroy
```

Also tried restarting the server a couple of times. Same error. I am sure I have not changed anything. But being a complete newbie to rails, I could have done something by mistake. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have another rails server instance running which is not the depot app. Try checking the rails server log on the terminal

The same problem like this thread, [Why do I get a No Route Matches [GET] "/products" when the route exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965608/why-do-i-get-a-no-route-matches-get-products-when-the-route-exists), ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I obviously missed the duplicate thread. I did not realize that the server was app specific. I was working on two apps. I stopped the server and restarted from the depot application.
I come from glassfish, WAS where I start the server and deploy different applications to it. I will learn more about rails server as I go along. Thanks for your answer again.